# Sharepoint Timer Job debuggging unable to set the Breakpoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, breakpoints, timer-jobs

I have a little problem. I'm trying to add a timer job following this tutorial : http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/

I came to the point where my timer job is enabled and is launching every five minutes. 
The problem is that it doesn't execute all the Execute method.

```
    public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
    {

        // get a reference to the current site collection's content database

        SPWebApplication webApplication = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;

        SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApplication.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];

        // get a reference to the "ListTimerJob" list in the RootWeb of the first site collection in the content database

        SPList Listjob = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["Liens"];

        // create a new list Item, set the Title to the current day/time, and update the item

        SPListItem newList = Listjob.Items.Add();

        //newList["URL"] = "http://"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+".fr";

        //newList.Update();

    }
```

I attached the debugger to the OWSTIMER.EXE. 
If i try to add a breakpoint at the line : SPList ListJob = ..., it's ok, 
But if i try to add a new breakpoint at the next line (SPListItem newList = ...) then i have the following message : 
"The following breakpoint cannot be set : ... 
The CLR was unable to set the breakpoint".

Does anyone has any idea how i can make it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be attaching to the correct service. See [How to: Debug a Timer Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798310.aspx) to double check your steps.

Also, as pointed out in this comment, you should restart the timer service when deploying a timer job:

> mark
>
> February 11, 2011 at 4:41 am
>
> There is a very important step that
>   needs to be completed with any Timer Project. You hav to recycle the
>   SharPoint timer service in between deployments. Best way to do this is
>   to add
>
> net stop SPTimerV4 – Pre Build
>
> net start SPTimerV4 – Post Build
>
> to your sharepoint project. If you do not do the above – you will be
>   puzzled as to why your code seems not to be up to date. The reason is
>   that the timer service Caches the assembly with your class. This can
>   cost you hours of troubleshooting, in trying to identify why your code
>   does not deploy.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know you had to stop and restart the SPTimer thing ;)

Comment: Yes, the restart of the timer service is very important! Can lead to really strange behavior when forgotten. For example if you modify a method the timerjob would still use the old method.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project configuration is in Debug mode (in Release mode compiler is setting is enabled for optimized code). Refer to this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/09/01/troubleshooting-common-breakpoint-problems-in-the-visual-studio-debugger-part-i.aspx)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. My solution has been deployed in Debug mode ... and optimize code is unchecked. Do you have any clue what else it could be ?